# ¿Porque me sale error table id=MainContent_tabla - Ajax. Al intentar hacer lazy loading?

Tags: javascript, c#, datatables

Lo que quiero hacer es un datatable con carga floja, que vaya cargando los datos de acuerdo a lo que se le vaya pidiendo.

Codigo de c#:

```
public partial class ConsultarEvidencia : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private int conta = 0;
        public string Inicio="";
        public string Fin = "";

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }
        public void btnOk_T_Onclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            HistoryBI historyBi=new HistoryBI();

            Inicio = dtInicio.Text;
            Fin = dtFin.Text;

            data = historyBi.ConsultarEvidencia(Inicio,Fin);


            //DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Ned-Design\Documents\projects\NederaV4\Administrators\Temp");//Assuming Test is your Folder
            //FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.png"); //Getting Text files

            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl createI = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("i");
            createI.ID = "createI";
            string str ="";



            foreach (DataRow dtRow in data.Rows)
            {

                TableRow row = new TableRow();

                for (int i=0;i<dtRow.ItemArray.Length;i++)
                {
                    TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
                        cell1.Text = dtRow[i].ToString();

                   row.Cells.Add(cell1);

                }

                tabla.Rows.Add(row);

            }



        }


    }
```

Codigo de Datatble en jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {


            $("[id$='dtInicio'],[id$='dtFin']").datepicker($.datepicker.regional["<%= Session["Lang"] %>"]);


            $('#MainContent_tabla').DataTable({
                dom: 'Blfrtip',
                buttons: [
                    'excelHtml5',
                    'pdfHtml5'
                ],
                columns: [
                    { title: "Id del Usuario" },
                    { title: "Nombre" },
                    { title: "Lectura de QR" },
                    { title: "Toma de evidencia" },
                    { title: "Diferencia" },
                    {title: "Placas"},
                    { title: "Imagen", "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                        return '<center><a class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:24px;cursor:pointer;" href=/Temp/'+full[6]+'></a></center>';
                    }
                    }
                ],
                "language": {
                    "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ Registros por pagina",
                    "zeroRecords": "No hay ningun registro que coincida",
                    "info": "Mostrando pagina _PAGE_ of _PAGES_",
                    "infoEmpty": "No hay registros disponibles",
                    "infoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total records)",
                    "search": "Buscar Palabra:",
                    "paginate": {
                        "previous": "Siguiente",
                        "next": "Anterior"
                    }
                },
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax": "ConsultarEvidencia.aspx.cs",
                "deferLoading": 57

            });
        });
```

El error de consola es:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No me funciona el datatable, ¿que estoy realizando mal?

Answer (score 0):

El error 404 significa que el recurso solicitado no fue encontrado.

Tienes un error al asignar la propiedad `"ajax": "ConsultarEvidencia.aspx.cs"` ya que con ASP.NET no debes llamar al nombre del archivo donde se encuentra el código fuente como se hace con PHP, si no que debes crear un método dentro de tu clase que retorne la información necesaria para llenar el DataTable y a este método es al que debes llamar.

**CODEBEHIND**

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string GetData()
{
    return "Hello World!!";
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

Para asignarlo al DataTable seria:

```
"ajax": "ConsultarEvidencia.aspx/GetData"
```